# Slow performance of pandas timestamp vs datetime

Tags: python, performance, datetime, numpy, pandas

I seem to be running into unexpectedly slow performance of arithmetic operations on pandas.Timestamp vs python regular datetime() objects.
Here is a benchmark that demonstrates:

```
import datetime
import pandas
import numpy

# using datetime:
def test1():
    d1 = datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 0)
    d2 = datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 15)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

    count = 0
    for i in range(500000):
        if d2 - d1 > delta:
            count += 1

# using pandas:
def test2():
    d1 = pandas.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 0)
    d2 = pandas.datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 15)
    delta = pandas.Timedelta(minutes=30)

    count = 0
    for i in range(500000):
        if d2 - d1 > delta:
            count += 1

# using numpy
def test3():
    d1 = numpy.datetime64('2015-03-20 10:00:00')
    d2 = numpy.datetime64('2015-03-20 10:00:15')
    delta = numpy.timedelta64(30, 'm')

    count = 0
    for i in range(500000):
        if d2 - d1 > delta:
            count += 1


  time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
  test1()
  time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
  test2()
  time3 = datetime.datetime.now()
  test3()
  time4 = datetime.datetime.now()

  print('DELTA test1: ' + str(time2-time1))
  print('DELTA test2: ' + str(time3-time2))
  print('DELTA test3: ' + str(time4-time3))
```

And corresponding results on my machine (python3.3, pandas 0.15.2):

```
DELTA test1: 0:00:00.131698
DELTA test2: 0:00:10.034970
DELTA test3: 0:00:05.233389
```

Is this expected?
Are there ways to eliminate the performance problem other than switching code to Python's default datetime implementation as much as possible?

Comment: To focus my question: I am aware that pandas and numpy are intended for vectorized processing.

Comment: The issue arises from the interface between the parts of the application that do vector processing and parts that work on discrete values/events: the discrete processing code gets a hit if provided with pandas datetime representation.

Comment: OK, in that case, if your benchmarks represent your use case, there is absolutely no reason to use numpy or pandas datetime.  Below I have constructed an alternate example showing a case where pandas datetime would be faster.  Of course, I can't be sure how well that represents your use case.

Comment: Also, you might consider posting a simplified version of your actual code and asking if anyone has ideas for speeding it up.  It's often easier for folks to give specific and practical answers to those sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar results on my machine:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s "from datetime import datetime, timedelta; d1, d2 = datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 0), datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 15); delta = timedelta(minutes=30)" "(d2 - d1) > delta"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.107 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s "from numpy import datetime64, timedelta64; d1, d2 = datetime64('2015-03-20T10:00:00Z'), datetime64('2015-03-20T10:00:15Z'); delta = timedelta64(30, 'm')" "(d2 - d1) > delta"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.35 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s "from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta; d1, d2 = Timestamp('2015-03-20T10:00:00Z'), Timestamp('2015-03-20T10:00:15Z'); delta = Timedelta(minutes=30)" "(d2 - d1) > delta"
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.9 usec per loop
```

`datetime` is several times faster than corresponding `numpy`, `pandas` analogs.

```
$ python -c "import numpy, pandas; print(numpy.__version__, pandas.__version__)"
('1.9.2', '0.15.2')
```

It is not clear why the difference is so large. It is true that `numpy`, `pandas` code is optimized for vectorized operations. But it is not obvious why these particular scalar operations are two orders of magnitude slower e.g., the adding of the explicit timezone does not slowdown `datetime.datetime` code:

```
$ python3 -mtimeit -s "from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone; d1, d2 = datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc), datetime(2015, 3, 20, 10, 0, 15, tzinfo=timezone.utc); delta = timedelta(minutes=30)" "(d2 - d1) > delta"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0939 usec per loop
```

To workaround the issue, you could try to convert native date/time types en masse into simpler (faster) analogs (e.g., POSIX timestamp represented as a float) if you can't use vectorized operations.

Comment: Thanks J.F and John for your answers.
Bottom line: pandas for batch processing, python for discrete.