# How do I vectorize a boolean operation on a numpy array of datetimes where the boolean operation compares datetime object attributes?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

Is there a way to use numpy's vectorization capabilities when doing a boolean operation on an array of datetime objects where you want to compare attributes of datetime objects.

My naive first attempt was:

```
import datetime as dtm
import numpy as np
dt = np.array([dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,6,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,5,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2013,1,4,13,3,1), dtm.datetime(2013,1,5,22,2,1)])

bool = (dt.year == 2014)
```

That gave me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'year'
```

which was obvious in retrospect.

I don't think that my second naive attempt was vectorizable, but thought it would get the job done:

```
bool = np.array([dts.year == 2014 for dts in dt])
```

However, I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong in this statement.

I would prefer a vectorizable solution, and I can do this using a for loop, but I think I should at least be able to do this in one line similar to my second attempt.

Is it possible to vectorize this statement?  If not, what am I doing wrong in my second attempt?  Thanks.

Comment: The invalid syntax is probably because you need parentheses, so that you have one boolean object of which to make the list

Comment: There must be something else wrong, I just tried it and I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Ilja OK, when I tested your comment the first time I tested it using dt14=[(dts==2014) for dts in dt], which is where I was trying to get to.  I neglected the second []'s, so dt14=[[(dts==2014) for dts in dt]] works.  Thank you!

Comment: well, I meant your first attempt :) good, that you found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could, as you said, `vectorize`.

```
import datetime as dtm
import numpy as np
dt = np.array([dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,6,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,5,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), dtm.datetime(2013,1,4,13,3,1), dtm.datetime(2013,1,5,22,2,1)])

is_2014 = np.vectorize(lambda d: d.year == 2014)

bool_ = is_2014(dt)
```

Note that `np.vectorize` does not necessarily provide better performance than a pure Python loop and primarily serves as syntactic sugar.

Comment: From the numpy docs for vectorize:

The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

So this is not an effective optimization which vectorization is the normally the use case for.

Comment: @iantbutler note that neither the question nor the answer make any refernece to performance. Of course, this is an old post and there are better ways to approach the problem.

Comment: I arrived here after searching something along the lines of "vectorizing a boolean operation" with the full need for performance and given that your post came up on google high up in the results and to me is misleading as its not truly a vectorization per the docs. I don't believe it is unreasonable to clarify for others who may wind up this way arriving from the same or similar google search.

Comment: Sounds fair, it seems that many people expect performance benefits from `np.vectorize` based on the function name. I edited the answer to clarify the performance aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ser = pd.Series([dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), 
                     dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), 
                     dtm.datetime(2014,1,6,12,2,1), 
                     dtm.datetime(2014,1,5,12,2,1), 
                     dtm.datetime(2014,1,4,12,2,1), 
                     dtm.datetime(2013,1,4,13,3,1), 
                     dtm.datetime(2013,1,5,22,2,1)])

>>> ser[ser.dt.year==2014]
0   2014-01-04 12:02:01
1   2014-01-04 12:02:01
2   2014-01-06 12:02:01
3   2014-01-05 12:02:01
4   2014-01-04 12:02:01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or the bools as NumPy array:

```
>>> (ser.dt.year==2014).values
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I just realized that I neglected to ask if pandas vectorizes its operations.  I have played around with it a little in the past but I am still new to python and decided to wait until I was more comfortable with the tools that I already had.  But if pandas vectorizes operations maybe I should start learning a little more about it now that I am more comfortable with some of the other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try [numpy's own datetime64 dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html). You may need to do some arithmetic to get out the years. Alternatively, you could use an array with Unix timestamp integers.

Comment: I am assuming that numpy must be able to use datetime64 more efficiently or it would not have been developed.  I work with a lot of code using the datetime module, so I wonder what the advantages of switching to using datetime64 are.  Is it significantly more efficient?  Are there other advantages?  I have noticed datetime64 mentioned before, but have never investigated its advantages.

Comment: It probably does depend a bit on the problem at hand (compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186939/slow-performance-of-pandas-timestamp-vs-datetime and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77582/speeding-up-python-date-conversion-function-currently-using-list-comprehension-a), but I think for your problem it should be faster (if the array is large enough). Disadvantages are that the interface isn't as nice as that of datetime (there's no `.year` etc. methods).